# 12.10 system settings removed

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors, system-settings

I just tried to find a solution for dual monitorsetup, installing gconf-editor and "additional drivers" on my ubuntu 12.10 cairo-dock desktop laptop.
actually I deinstalled my bluetooth programms before this, because there was no connection to my nokia phone.

the result is, that I cant even change my desktop background image.

In the softwarecenter now I installed "system settings (systemsettings)" but it shows me only the KDE System Settings application.

what now? I cant use the second monitor.

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Gnome Control Center with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```